Debian firewall allowing connections on port 3000
I have a Debian server running Rocket Chat. The web interface is on port 3000 and works.
I am trying to configure LetsEncrypt and checking the firewall it appears only port 22 is permitted.
How can I access the webserver on port 3000 if only 22 is permitted?

Does this mean for LE I need to add 80 & 443 or is everything somehow already open?

I can't find a suitable duplicate Q&A but (depending on the docker version and configuration) when you use docker to expose a port, it creates a custom firewall rule to make that happen. It doesn't use ufw for that , rather docker manipulates iptables or nftables directly. See for example the output of sudo iptables-save

Generally, ufw only manages a subset of the iptables rules. To see all firewall rules you need to check iptables directly.
